# Why my python code is showing value error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, indentation, valueerror

I am writing this python code to check DNA sequence file. The output will be the name of person to whom this DNA is matched.
This link has the description of assignment.
https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/psets/6/dna/
But when i try to run the code its showing value error.

Kindly someone let me know the error in the code.
I am new to the programming.

```
from sys import argv, exit
import csv

def max_Reptitions_of_substrings(dnaSequences , substring):
 arr = [0] * len(dnaSequences)
 for i in range(len(dnaSequences) - len(substring), -1, -1):
     if dnaSequences[i: i + len(substring)] == substring:
       if i + len(substring) > len(dnaSequences) - 1:
           arr[i] = 1
       else:
           arr[i] = 1 + arr[i + len(substring)]
 return max(arr)

def print_Matching(reading, newdata):
    for i in reading:
        human = i[0]
        value = [int(digit) for digit in i[1:]]
        if value == newdata:
         print(human)
         return
    print("No match")


def main():
  if len(argv) != 3:
      print("Missing Command line Argument")
      exit(1)
  
with open(argv[1], 'r') as database:
       reading = csv.reader(database)
       sequences = next(reading)[1:]
   
with open(argv[2], 'r') as sequenceFilestrong text:
    dnaSequences = sequenceFile.read() 
    newdata = [max_Reptitions_of_substrings(dnaSequences, substr) for substr in sequences]
    print_Matching(reading, newdata)
```

Value error shown is as

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dna.py", line 36, in <module>
    print_Matching(reading, newdata)
  File "dna.py", line 15, in print_Matching
    for i in reading:
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

Answer (score 3):

The error message is pretty explicit and spot-on:

> ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

You are opening your CSV file in a `with` block and create a new CSV reader based on that file. But at the end of the `with` block, the file is closed. `reading` now refers to a CSV reader that’s linked to a closed file connection.

Hence the error.

Answer (score 1):

Try to look at code indentation, it's very important in Python. First *with* should be inside *function main*, second *with* should be inside first *with*.
**Why?**
Just look at the code. In print matching you're using *reading* csv.reader, which right now try to use already closed file passed as argument.

Comment: Thanks Macialek  Your Hint Solved my problem